# Is it possible to make letters upright (non-italic) in equations in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting

On [this forum answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HqsiBA9i8wU) on Google Docs it is mentioned that commands such as `\mathrm{}` should be possible. Just like in regular LaTeX (or MathJax).

I cannot make this command work on my page, though. Other simpler commands such as `\frac`, `\sqrt` and `\alpha` work and are shortcuts for the menu buttons. But the `\mathrm` (and also not `\text` and others I've tried), which should make the text upright, does not work and there is no roman ('non-italic') button in the equation menu.

So, I guess the question is two-fold:

Why don't the shortcuts mentioned in this forum answer work for me?
And what is a method to make non-italic symbols?

Comment: The referred question is very old (2010). As a side note, any equation shortcut doesn't work for me at this time. Link to the official help article: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749

Comment: The link in the question is broken. Apparently the referred content was not archived in archive.org.

Answer (score 1):

There are upright latin characters available through the `Insert > Special Characters` menu item when typing in an equation. From the dialogue that opens, choose the category `Symbol` and sub-category `Maths Alphanumeric`, and choose the character you need. To make it quicker, you can also search for *mathematical sans*, or *mathematical bold*, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do it for normal text, but `\cos` and `\sin` work